# Откуда в русском языке слово "филин"?

Tags: этимология

Насколько я знаю, исконно в русском языке буквы Ф не было, и все слова, начинающиеся на эту букву, заимствованные. Но слово "филин", по-моему, исконно русское. Откуда же оно взялось в русском языке?

Comment: Повтор http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8361/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Историко-этимологический  словарь  П.Я. Черных  указывает  на  слово  квилин ( хвилин )  как  исходное.  Квилити  -  стонать, жаловаться.  Сохранилось  в  украинском  языке  и  по  отношению  к  птицам  и  к  людям.  К  тому  времени,  когда  это  слово  оказалось  записано ( как  прозвище,  правда ) - в  15  веке,  звук  "ф" языке  уже  был.